# Sheer vs daylight blinds?

Tags: windows, blinds

I suspect it refers to the fabric type, but what do shops mean when they refer to "sheer" blinds as opposed to "daylight" ones?  Here's an example of two similar blinds with these fabrics:

[Sheer](https://www.johnlewis.com/house-by-john-lewis-sheer-roller-blind/p3207897) | [Daylight](https://www.johnlewis.com/house-by-john-lewis-daylight-roller-blind/p3207895)

The "daylight" one looks whiter, but they are not described as "beige" and "white"; is there some other difference in the two fabrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the language offered.

**Sheer**

> This sheer blind allows light to flow into a room while offering privacy, so it's a great option for a window that is overlooked.

**Daylight**

> This daylight blind offers privacy, while still allowing some light into your room.

Comparing the two, it would seem that Sheer is designed to allow maximum light while concealing detail. I assume that shapes may be visible, as they would be in [sheer clothing](http://www.forever21.com/images/1_front_750/00191215-03.jpg). Daylight apparently allows less light to pass, but probably conceals shapes for greater privacy.